# How to use JSF2.0 view scope in cluster environment?

Tags: jsf-2, cluster-computing

I want to use **JSF2.0** in cluster environment. I'm building a **JPA2.0 + Spring 3.0 + JSF2.0** stack. I know how to replicate session scoped beans. But how to replicate view scoped beans? I plugged view scope into **Spring 3.0** from here
http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0/

The idea is the same as in JS2.0 on JEE6 server - put a bean into the view map (`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap()`)

The problem is :
I've opened `index.xhtml` on **node 1**. `View-scoped` bean was created. I clicked something and the `postback` request got onto **node 2** - where the view doesn't exist.

Is it possible to have this in cluster environment? Should I use only session and `request` scope?

On the other hand JSF view-state may not work properly in cluster environment. How to use JSF on cluster?

Comment: How exactly did you replicate the session? Does the session scoped beans work? The view scope is basically stored in the session.

Comment: I'm using built-in Tomcat session replication (DeltaManager). I'm looking at session in Javamelody but there are only session beans.

Comment: It looks like Sticky Sessions do the trick. All requests from one user go to one server. When server fails, sessions are handled on backup but the view expires. I can live with that.